# Use paste with row-major input

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, paste

I can create a file with multiple columns from a single-column input via `paste` like this:

```
some_command | paste - -
```

This works when `some_command` produces the data in column-major format. In other words, the input

```
1
2
3
4
```

results in the output

```
1   2
3   4
```

However, I want the opposite, i.e. I want

```
1   3
2   4
```

Background: I want to collect all *N*’th columns from *M* files into one aggregate file. I tried doing this via:

```
cut -f 5 "${files[@]}" | paste - - - - - …
```

(with *M* `-`s). But as mentioned before, this doesn’t work, as `paste` expects column-major input. I can’t help but think that there should be a coreutils (or pure Bash) solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correctly understand the question, you could try with `pr`:

```
cut -f 5 "${files[@]}" | pr -5 -s' ' -t -l 40
```

where `-5` is the number of columns, `-s' '` is the separator (space) and `-l 40` is the page length (40 lines).

---

Without `coreutils`, one could use `split` to create pieces of *N* lines:

```
split -lN infile
```

or

```
some_command | split -lN
```

and then `paste` them together:

```
paste x* > outfile
rm x*
```

Comment: This works, but I think by “line length” you mean “number of lines/rows”.