# Transform row of integer into multi-column output

Tags: linux, bash, csv-simple

I am trying to get the input of a file to generate me a list with rows and columns of that numbers in sorted order. This will be use to generate a printable document later, so i am able to replace the steps currently used manually in Excel.

Raw data are integers between 1 and 20000.
suppose either:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
```

or

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

The List is sorted by numeric value and seperated by whitespaces.
Optionally i can seperate the values by \n or anything else if that helps me get me to my goal

The column amount should be 7, but most likely i will be able to change that myself later on.

My wanted output:

```
1 40 80
2 41 81 
3 42 82 
4 43 83
```

What i tried while hoping to figure it out during reading some unix.se questions, other suggestions on SF, manpage of column, fml etc.

```
for value in $(cat /tmp/list); do      printf "%-8s\n" "${value}"; done|column -x
```

output (simplified, tab character between):

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
...
```

Next try was a suggestion on Serverfault:

```
cat /tmp/list |fmt |column -t
```

output:

```
1    2    3    4    5 
6    7    8    9    10
```

I would like to understand where my issue with understanding during the process is, not just the raw solution (which would help though).

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input file in your question?

Comment: Most solutions are going to turn every `n` lines into a row of `n` columns, because that doesn't require any memory.  What you want requires reading the whole input to know what should be in the last column of the first row.  Thus, tools like `pr` are what you need.

Comment: Very similar to [Use paste with row-major input](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171507)

Comment: @don_crissti correct, seems it is the same i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo {1..20000} | tr " " "\n" | sort -n | pr -T3 -s" " -l 6667
```

Output:

```
1 6668 13335
2 6669 13336
3 6670 13337
4 6671 13338
5 6672 13339
6 6673 13340
7 6674 13341
8 6675 13342
9 6676 13343
10 6677 13344
11 6678 13345
.
.
.
```

To test with your file:

```
tr " " "\n" < file | sort -n | pr -T3 -s" " -l 6667
```

It does not matter if the 20000 numbers are all in a row or in a column.

Comment: looks nice, will test this tomorrow, thanks for the "pr" tool

Comment: pr -7 -s' ' -t -l 80 most likely will be the one i use.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your input consists of newline-separated numbers, such as:

```
1
2
3
...
```

it is a matter of a simple `sed` script to put them into columns:

```
$ sed -n '{N;N;N;N;N;N;s/\n/\t/g;p}'
```

When the script encounters a line, it reads 6 more lines (`N;N;N;N;N;N`) into the buffer, replaces each newline within the buffer for a tab (`s/\n/\t/g`) and prints the buffer out (`p`). The result:

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7
8    9    10   11   12   13   14
...
```

**Note:** The number of lines in the input needs to be a multiple of seven, any remaining entries will be dropped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
However it seems i was unclear in how the output has to be formatted.
I need the integers as following: f.e. row 1: 1 100 200 300 400 500 600 700
Row 2: 2 101 201 301 401 501 601

this is the problem i am facing right now. Adding the output based on f.e. 7 values in one row could be a matter of a simple for loop with an echo.